# *ngFor... targeting a specific element in the loop (with an event)

Tags: angular, ngfor

So this is the situation: I have a list of objects being generated from a ngFor loop. I am trying to click on a single element, and change the contents of the markup for that particular element. When a user clicks the element, I want the track number to display "playing". The way I have it programmed, it applies the change to every element in the loop.

HTML:

```
<li class="song-block"
      *ngFor='let song of songsToDisplay'
      (click)="getSong(song)">
    <div (click)="play()" class="song-card">
      <p  *ngIf="!isPlaying"class="song-number">{{song.tracknumber}}</p>
      <p *ngIf="isPlaying"class="song-number">Playing</p>
      <p class="song-name">{{song.name}}</p>
      <p class="song-length">{{song.length}}</p>
      <svg class="explicit"
          *ngIf="albumToDisplay.isExplicit === 'true'"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
          focusable="false">
            <g class="style-scope iron-icon">
              <path d="M19 3H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm-4 6h-4v2h4v2h-4v2h4v2H9V7h6v2z"></path></g></svg>
    </div>
  </li>
```

TypeScript:

```
isPlaying: boolean = false; 

play(){
    this.isPlaying = true;
    console.log(this.isPlaying)
  }
```

Here is a visual of the app:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onfwz.png

How can I target just one specific element within that loop? I feel like I am missing something incredibly simple here that I should not be missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `isPlaying` property to each item of `songsToDisplay`, and change target song `isPlaying` to `true` after target song is clicked. Then display each song's playing status based on it's own `isPlaying` property.

Template:

```
<div (click)="play(song)" class="song-card">
  <p *ngIf="!song.isPlaying"class="song-number">{{song.tracknumber}}</p>
  <p *ngIf="song.isPlaying"class="song-number">Playing</p>
  ...
</div>
```

TS:

```
play(song){
  song.isPlaying = true;
  //console.log(this.isPlaying)
}
```

BTW, remember to roll `song.isPlaying` back to `false` when the song meets it's end.